# Iterate through a file and an array simultaneously python for loop

Tags: python, arrays, file, for-loop

I am trying to iterate through a file and add a new column into it instead of one that is present in the file using two concurrent for loops. But i dont know how to iterate the array part.

I have an array aa=[1,2,3,4,5]
My file is:

```
I   a   0
II   b   0
III   c   0
IV   d   0
V   f   0
```

I want it like:

```
I   a   1
II   b   2
III   c   3
IV   d   4
V   f   5
```

I tried python code:

```
cmg=[1,2,3,4,5]
fh=open("plink5.map",'r')
fhnew=open("plink5.out",'w+')
for line,i in zip(fh,(0,len(cmg)-1,1)):
    line=line.strip('\n')
    aa=line.split('\t')
    aanew=str(aa[0])+"\t"+str(aa[1])+"\t"+str(cmg[i])
    print(aanew)
   fhnew.write(aanew)
fh.close()
fhnew.close()
```

I get error in the array iteration part

Comment: Why don't you just use a variable `arrayIndex` in your for loop that you manually increment each time?

Comment: @rob:i tried that. But the first value of the array is only getting appended

Comment: actually it was my bad. i initialised the arrayindex inside the for loop. so everytime the first value got stored. i fixed it now. Thanks for ur time sir

Answer (score 2):

What you were trying to do is:

```
for line,i in zip(fh,range((0,len(cmg)  ,1))):
                     ^^^^^            ^^
```

But what would be easier:

```
for line,x in zip(fh, cmg):
```

Comment: thank you. I was trying to iterate through the array instead of taking the value as such! thank you sir

Comment: One more doubt sir. While writing float values into a file i have all of then rounded off with e notations like 8.9+e05  instead of 0.000089. How do i get this long formatted float value in the file??

Comment: @Vignesh that sounds like a new question!